# ZXing : Error message appshell, Zxing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.ZXingScannerView Renderer.LayoutSubviews

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, zxing, app-shell

I have a ZXing Nuget Package used within an AppShell on a page.
It works well outside the AppShell but when I add it to the appshell.
I get this error message when the page is visited.

xamarin object reference not set to an instance of an object at Zxing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.ZXingScannerView Renderer.LayoutSubviews

This only happens in the iOS Project.

Here's the XAML section of the Scanner View.

```
 <StackLayout FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                 <RelativeLayout x:Name="ZXingScannerViewRelativeLayout"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                 FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Center">
                                          <zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="ZXingScannerView1" 
                                                    IsScanning="{Binding IsScanning}" 
                                                    ScanResultCommand="{Binding ScanResultCommand}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                                    AutomationId = "zxingScannerView"
                                                    IsAnalyzing="{Binding IsAnalyzing}"
                                                    Result="{Binding ScannedResult, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                    IsTorchOn="{Binding IsTorchOn}" 
                                                    IsVisible="{Binding ScannerViewIsVisible}"
                                                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width}"
                                                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height}">
                                          </zxing:ZXingScannerView>
                                 </RelativeLayout>

                           

                       </StackLayout>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can share the worked code and unworked code here, that will be helpful to check where problem is.